Problem when using select2 in a dynamic form
I'm using extensions dynamicform and select2 together in one form.:
wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget 
kartik\select2\Select2

It works fine at first, but when adding another field, it just looks like loading:

How do i see what is causing the problem?
The code of the fields:
*$data has approximately 2000 records*
<?php

    $data = ArrayHelper::map(Alimento::find()->orderBy("alimento ASC")->all(), 'id', 'alimento');

    echo $form->field($modelItemreceita, "[{$i}]alimento_id")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
         'data' => $data,
         'name' => "[{$i}]alimento_id",
         'language' => 'pt-br',
         'options' => ['placeholder' => '-- Selecione o ingrediente --'],
    ]);
?>

<?= $form->field($modelItemreceita, "[{$i}]qtde")->textInput(['type' => 'number', 'maxlength' => true]) ?>


Check your browser console for js error. Remove id/name from select2 if you are assigning them manually.

I wasn't able to identify anything that would help me in the console

I found a post with the same problem and among the possible solutions, this one worked for me:
In composer.json changing wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform to dev-master worked for me. kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 version is 2.0.0
